# i want to calculate the quantity for those products which belongs to same category

Tags: php, mysql

for this i have 3 tables

```
categories(id,category) 

products(id,category_id,name)

productstock(id,product_id,quantity)
```

the query written for this

```
    select categories.category,sum(productstock.quantity)
    from categories
    inner join productStock on products.id=productstock.product_id
    inner join products on categories.id=products.category_id
    group by category;
```

it would be a great help

Comment: What is your question? what is wrong with your query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using **LEFT JOIN**.

```
SELECT c.category, SUM(quantity) AS 'sum_qty' FROM productstock a
LEFT JOIN products b ON a.product_id=b.id
LEFT JOIN categories c ON b.category_id=c.id
GROUP BY category_id;
```

Comment: @Rana kindly mark the Solution as accepted if this solves your question, thank you and have a great day.